# Text got cut off when strange chars inside when trying to save into TEXT field

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, utf-8, psycopg2

Having a text like that in a file. I want to insert that text in my database (UTF8 encoding by the way).

```
OK:     "Spanning op P4V2 (TP2)" : 4.00 V DC <= 4.20 V DC
OK:     "Spanning op P1V8_EHSX_BGS2 (TP1030)" : 1.81 V DC >= 1.71 V DC
OK:     "Spanning op P1V8_EHSX_BGS2 (TP1030)" : 1.81 V DC <= 1.89 V DC
LOG:    Waiting for barebox command prompt
LOG:    ^@^@Starting Bootlets...
LOG:
LOG:    Configured for DCDC_BATT only power source.
LOG:    Initialized 1 ram bank(s)
LOG:    Starting secondary bootloader
```

The table has a field "results" with type "TEXT". However the file get cut off when finds the "^@" characters. Everything after that is not saved in my database.

I have tried many things like:

```
results = results.encode('utf-8')
self.db.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
c.execute("INSERT INTO ats2_testrun (serial_number_id, test_system_id, date, status_ok, results, author, svn_url, svn_revision_number, service_report_id)  +
                  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);",(sid, tsid, tstamp, ok, results, author, svn_url, svn_revision_number, service_report_id))
```

But it doesn't work. Somebody told me to transform that field into a binary one, but if there is a way to save that into a TEXT field. I don't care the strange chars "^@" so they can be removed.

Comment: Where soes the `^@^@Starting Bootlets...` line in the logfile stem from? BTW: `^@` is a textual representation for a binary nul (0x00) character; so this is possibly an unitialised buffer in the client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x00` (`^@`) is a string terminator. It is the only character you can not save in a 0x00-terminated field (which TEXT is).

Replace the chars and you will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I did something like: logtext = logtext.replace('\x00', '')